# vuetify. v-hover не работает

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

Выношу логику из вёрстки в методы. Столкнулся с проблемой: не работает `v-bind` `hover`, если его вынести в метод.

Рабочий пример:

```
<template>
    <v-container>
        <v-hover v-slot:default="{ hover }">
            <v-card
                width="344"
                height="480"
                :elevation="course.available ? (hover ? this.settings.hover_elevation : this.settings.elevation) : this.settings.elevation"
            >
                <v-card-text>
                    {{ course.title }}
                </v-card-text>
            </v-card>
        </v-hover>
    </v-container>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "CourseCard",
        props: ['course'],
        created() {
            this.settings = this.$store.state.settings;
        },
        data: () => ( {
            settings: null,
            hover: false,
        } ),
    }
</script>
```

Нерабочий пример:

```
<template>
    <v-container>
        <v-hover v-slot:default="{ hover }">
            <v-card
                width="344"
                height="480"
                :elevation="hovered(course, hover)"
            >
                <v-card-text>
                    {{ course.title }}
                </v-card-text>
            </v-card>
        </v-hover>
    </v-container>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "CourseCard",
        props: ['course'],
        created() {
            this.settings = this.$store.state.settings;
        },
        methods: {
            hovered: (course, hover) => {
                return course.available ? (hover ? this.settings.hover_elevation : this.settings.elevation) : this.settings.elevation;
            },
        },
        data: () => ( {
            settings: null,
            hover: false,
        } ),
    }
</script>
```

Не ясно, почему не получается вынести логику в метод `hovered`. Как это связано с устройством `v-hover`?